# Conversion of decimal into binary using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, return-value

I want to convert the decimal number into a binary number using recursion in java. I tried a lot but unable to do it. Here is my code:

```
public class DecimalToBinary {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(conversion(2));
    }

    public static int conversion(int n) {
         return reconversion(n);
    }

    public static int reconversion(int n) {
        if(n <= 0)
            return 0;
        else {

            return  (int) (n/2 + conversion(n/2));

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer values are already in binary.  The fact that they appear as digits 0 thru 9 when you print them is because they are converted to a string of decimal digits.  So you need to return a String of binary digits like so.

```java
   public static String conversion(int n) {
      String b = "";
      if (n > 1) {
         // continue shifting until n == 1
         b = conversion(n >> 1);
      }
      // now concatenate the return values based on the logical AND
      b += (n & 1);
      return b;

   }
```

Comment: It `shifts` the value of `n` one bit to the right.  So if `n` is `101` in binary, it will now call conversion with `10`.

Comment: And what about the statement b+ = (n & 1); ?? I am unaware of ( n & 1). Kindly help me

Comment: That is a bit test for a value.  It does a logical AND operation with n and a give mask.  Since the mask is 1, it checks to see if the low order bit is set.  It if is (1 & 1) returns a 1.  If it isn't (0 & 1) returns a 0.  Other bit operations are ~ and ^ and | which are complement, exclusive OR, and OR.